# Angular2 importing components in modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a loading screen component that I would like to reuse across different components in different modules.

I have an AppModule

```
 @NgModule ( {
   declarations: [
     LoadingScreenComponent  //has tag app-loading-screen
   ],
   imports: [
    ReportsModule,DashboardModule
    ]

    });
export class AppModule {
 }
```

In the ReportsModule I have

```
     @NgModule ( {
   declarations: [
     ReportsComponent
   ],
    });
export class ReportsModule {
 }
```

In the ReportsComponent html file

```
<app-loading-screen></app-loading-screen>
```

When doing it this way am getting an error that

```
'app-loading-screen' is not a known element
```

Several other components in different modules also need to use the loading screen component.

Why does this fail yet i have included `LoadingScreenComponent` in the root module. Or how do i go about it?

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the LoadingScreenComponent as well?

Comment: the component has nothing but just a text showing loading.

Comment: Create a shared module and declare, export the LodingScreenModule and then add in both AppModule and ReportsModule.

Comment: also read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do **Loding screen component** as shared module and you import shared module both app module and report module

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
imports: [
],
declarations: [
 LoadingScreenComponent
],
providers: [

],
exports: [
   LoadingScreenComponent
]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then you can import shared module in both **dashboard module and report module**

Answer (score 2):

LoadingScreenComponent is declared in AppModule, but ReportsModule, which is imported to AppModule, doesn't know about LoadingScreenComponent. You need to refactor to make a common module to both and import LoadingScreenComponent there.

Comment: thanks this solves it, sample code has been provided by @robert below.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `LoadingScreenComponent` to exports array in the AppModule. This will make it globally accessible:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoadingScreenComponent  //has tag app-loading-screen
    ],
    imports: [
        ReportsModule,
        DashboardModule
    ],
    exports: [
        LoadingScreenComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Otherwise, the best way is to create a shared module and import that module to any other module where you want to use the `LoadingScreenComponent`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingScreenComponent } from '...'; //Path to the LoadingScreenComponent

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoadingScreenComponent
    ],    
    exports: [
        LoadingScreenComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And import it to other modules like this:

```
import { SharedModule } from '...'; //Path to the SharedModule

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ReportsComponent
    ],
    imports[
        SharedModule
    ]
})
export class ReportsModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared module like this and import in other modules.

shared.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
        imports: [
            //If needed
        ],
        declarations: [
          LoadingScreenComponent 
        ],
        exports:[LoadingScreenComponent]
 })
 export class SharedModule {}
```

In AppModule

```
 @NgModule ({
   imports: [
    SharedModule
    ]
  });
export class AppModule {}
```

In ReportModule

```
@NgModule ({
   declarations: [
     SharedMoudule,
     ReportsComponent
   ],
    });
export class ReportsModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `bootstrap: [ LoadingScreenComponent  ]` to your **NgModule**.

**Edit**

```
@NgModule ( {
   declarations: [
     LoadingScreenComponent  //has tag app-loading-screen
   ],
   imports: [
    ReportsComponent,DashboardModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [ LoadingScreenComponent ]

    });
export class AppModule {
 }
```

Also in your index what is defined there?

Normal you would add the report html to your main component not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the selector in your LoadingScreenComponent as shown below.
The selector will be used to app to the component

```
import {
   Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-loading-screen',
    templateUrl: 'loading-screen.component.html'
})

export class LoadingScreenComponent {}
```

Comment: its already include after generating the component with angular cli